# what to do with this code to fetch the current date matching record from database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

what i do more with this code to fetch current date records from mysql database table i want to fetch same day records from table date is present in my table in 'duedt' field from which i am matching current date here is code help me out thanks in advance

```
$curdate= date("Y-m-d"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ticketid,duedt  
FROM tickets   
WHERE duedt = 'curdate'
");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{   
$dayname='SAMEDDAY';

                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['ticketid'] . '</td>';
                             echo '<td>'. $row['duedt'] . '</td>';
                            // echo '<td>'. $row['WEEKDAY(duedt)'] . '</td>';
                             echo '<td>' .$dayname.  '</td>';

                         echo '<td>';   
                           echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-s" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick=window.open("detailticket.php?ticketid='.$row['ticketid'].'","Ratting","width=950,height=600,0,status=0,");>Detail</a>';
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                    //          echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-s" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick=window.open("collectticket.php?ticketid='.$row['ticketid'].'","Ratting","width=950,height=600,0,status=0,");>Complete</a>';

                            echo '</td>';

                            echo '</tr>';
                   } 
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
```

Comment: HINT:  `'curdate'` is a string literal in the SQL text. It's not a reference to a MySQL function, and it's not a PHP variable that's being interpreted/replaced with a value.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the PHP variable in your query, please try this:

```
$curdate = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT ticketid, duedt FROM tickets WHERE duedt = '" . $curdate . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Also, please consider using `mysqli_*` functions to access your database, as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions.

Comment: worked but not correctly it is not showing today date records showing records which have no date present in table

Comment: for null values, you can add `OR duedt IS NULL` to the query.

Comment: dnt need null date records i only want current date records

Comment: Without knowing what your database really contains, it's difficult to guess a solution :). `OR duedt > ''` should catch all empty values (empty strings and `NULL`)

Comment: Please update your original code with the actual table structure (the output of the MySQL command `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`, replacing `mytable` with the actual name of your table)

Comment: see today is Monday 04-05-2015 i want Monday records and tomorrow is Tuesday so tomorrow so tomarrow i need tuesday records so that my query get Tuesday record similarly for other weekdays.dates are already saved in table i just want to fetch current day date records i hope this help you to understand

Comment: got it by doing this WHERE DATE(duedt) = DATE(NOW())